# Basic help finding minimum values in a slice of a numpy array (or any array for that matter)?

Tags: python, list, numpy

This is probably very basic but I haven't been able to find the question on the site:

I have time series data and can only pass window length into the function when calling it. In my case, this is the 14-day low of daily price data, where the most recent price is the last value in the array/list.

For the most recent 14-day low, I can call

```
window_length = 14

w = window_length
np.nanmin(xyzlist[-w:], axis = 0)
```

but I need data not only for the most recent 14-day low, but also the trailing 2 14-day high and low data. 
My current thought process is to adjust the window size and just call on the oldest 14 days, so for the second day I would say

```
window_length = 15

w = window_length
np.nanmin(xyzlist[-w:-w+14], axis = 0)
```

However, this would not work for the most recent 14-day low as it ignores the value stored in [-1]. Honestly I could just solve this with an 'if' statement where if the window size == 14 I would do it the first way, otherwise I would do it the second way, but it feels sloppy.

I realize there is probably a very simple solution applicable not only to numpy arrays, so if anyone could help it would mean so much :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idiom that may feel slightly less awkward is:

```
np.nanmin(xyzlist[-w:(-w+14) or None], axis = 0)
```

Comment: This solution is more useful, opposed to just setting the slice to [0:14] as it allows you to iterate and pull all needed trailing values regardless of window size (as long as window size > needed range of course) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I way overthought this. I just needed to pass in

```
np.nanmin(xyzlist[0:14], axis = 0)
```

That way I can call in any window length I want and it will take the oldest 14 prices. It's been a really long day, sorry about that.